# @shopify/react-native-skia with expo

Tags: react-native, expo, skia

when I try to import hello world example from the the original web page, I get en error like;

ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "SkiaDomView" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
in SkiaDomView (created by SkiaDomView)
in SkiaDomView
in Unknown (created by HelloWorld)
in HelloWorld (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent)

from the console and the expo go.

Answer (score 1):

After I downgraded the version, it worked.

Comment: from and to what versions?